# How much space does Edubuntu take up once installed

Tags: edubuntu

Seems like Ubuntu takes up about 2.2 GB after installed on disk, but I can't find any information about an Edubuntu installation, nor how much space the Edubuntu-desktop package takes up. I would like to know the size for both 12.04 and 14.04 if there is a significant difference.

Comment: Support for 12.04 will end in some weeks, it makes few sense to still do a fresh install of that release.

Comment: it's a little bit less graphically intensive on these old computers, and is going in to a low-tech workspace with a bunch of other 12.04 systems. But yes, I should upgrade them

Answer (score 0):

Finally got lazy and just popped in an install disk. One of the checks it does is ">8.6 GB of storage", so I guess that's the answer